# JQuery and Javascript fade not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element, fadein

Jquery and Javascript do strange things. If you look to the code there is a "while" loop. It does 3 loops but only fades the last one (#c2).
Here is my code:

```
<div style="display:none" id="c0">Element 0</div>
<div style="display:none" id="c1">Element 1</div>
<div style="display:none" id="c2">Element 2</div>
<script>
var count = 0;
var exit = false;
var time = 300;

while(exit == false){
    if(document.getElementById("c" + count)){
        cual = "#c" + count;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(cual).fadeIn(time);
        });
    }
    else
        exit = true;
    count++;
    time += 100;
}

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is loaded after the DOM is loaded on the page, so you don't need to use `$(document).ready()`. I have tested the following script:

```
var count = 0;
var exit = false;
var time = 300;

while(exit == false){
    if(document.getElementById("c" + count)){
        cual = "#c" + count;
        $(cual).fadeIn(time);
    }
    else
        exit = true;
    count++;
    time += 100;
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see this is because the `cual` variable will hold the value `#c3` by the time the callbacks execute. Because `cual` is defined within a global scope, and not the callback scope, it is not bounded to the callback scoe.

There is a workaround for this, by adding an intermediary function, something like this:

```
function scheduleFade(count) {
    var cual = "#c" + count;
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(cual).fadeIn(time);
    });
}

while(exit == false) {
    if(document.getElementById("c" + count)) {
        scheduleFade(count);
    } else {
        exit = true;
    }
    count++;
    time += 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Update based on comments)

The variable `cual` is overwritten on each loop, but the code inside the `ondocumentready` event listener is only executed after the DOM is fully loaded. At this point the variable `cual` is only set to the name of the third element.

You can create an own visibility scope for that variable to make it available inside the event listener callback:

```
var count = 0;
var exit = false;
var time = 300;

while(exit == false){
    if(document.getElementById("c" + count)){
        cual = "#c" + count;
        $(document).ready((function() {
            var elementToFadeIn = cual;
            return function() {
                $(elementToFadeIn).fadeIn(time);
            }
        })());
    }
    else
        exit = true;
    count++;
    time += 100;
}
```

Here the variable `elementToFadeIn` is set inside an immediately-invoked-function, which also returns the event listener callback. That way, the locally defined `elementToFadeIn` will stay with name passed in on the current loop iteration.

–––––

On the other you are using jQuery, why do need the loop in the first place?

Just **include this code at the end of the page** (i.e. before the closing BODY tag) and you don't need the `ondocumentready` event, as all relevant parts of the DOM are loaded right before the closing BODY tag.

```
var time = 1000;
jQuery( '[id^="c"]' ).fadeIn( time );
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I'm not aware of such a limitation.